# JSTL fn:subStringBetween?

Tags: java, jstl

I have a string like this "Promote by abc@gmail.com" and I want to get the "abc" substring.

If I try individually,

```
${fn:subStringAfter("Promote by abc@gmail.com", "by ")} gives "abc@gmail.com"
```

Now I also want to eliminate the part after '@'.

I tried nesting the JSTL functions like this:

```
${fn:substringBefore(${fn:substringAfter("Promote by abc@gmail.com", "by ")}, "@")}
```

But nesting doesn't work. Only substringBefore and subStringAfter will work individually.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a variable to store your string manipulation function:

```
<c:set var = "yourString" value = "${fn:subStringAfter("Promote by abc@gmail.com", "by ")} " />
<c:set var = "yourString" value = "${fn:substringBefore(yourString, '@')}" />
```

Now `yourString` is set with the desired value.